# How to query Wordpress db for posts with specific tags within Codeigniter?

Tags: database, wordpress, codeigniter, tags

currently my code for pulling the entries is as follows, and it works:

```
$blog_data['posts'] = $this->wordpress_model->active()->limit(3)->order_by('post_date', 'DESC')->get_posts('post');
```

How do I go about specifying that I only want tags='tagname'?

Answer (score 0):

You should include **where('',array(tag=>"tagName"))** method